# iOS - how to adjust the scale of a slider

Tags: iphone, ios, slider, scaling

I have an app where I want to place an object within a photo and scale it to reflect the distance it should be from the camera.  At full size I want it to reflect approximately 10 meters away from the camera and at its smallest size I want it to be about 30 meters away.

Unfortunately, the slider seems to scale it almost infinitely, without looking very realistic in scaling.  What's the best way to accomplish this such that I get both minimum and maximum distances as well as making intermediate distances scale in a realistic fashion (i.e., each intermediate step reflecting the actual distance it should be from the camera)?

Comment: Have you set the sliders min value to 10 and max value to 30?

Comment: Is that all that is required?  I was thinking I needed to add some extra calculations to indicate what 10 and 30 actually mean.  For the minimumValue, that would, by default, be my 10 meter point. But how do I actually scale the object so that it is the right size per each "slider stop" up to the maximum of 30 meters?

Answer (score 1):

By default `UISlider`'s `minimumValue` and `maximumValue` are 0 and 1, respectively, which might explain the scaling behavior you're seeing. You can configure these values to simplify your calculations or, alternatively, scale the default 0-1 range to 10-30 meters.

Comment: Yes, but how does the slider have any concept of meters in the first place?  What additional calculations do I have to perform to make each "slider stop" reflect the actual size of the object that it should be at that given distance?

Comment: Sliders, of course, don't know anything about meters, grams or seconds. They just reflect numeric values, whatever they mean to your app. If you set the slider's minimum and maximum values to some _numbers_ of meters, you can safely think that its value means meters and the value is between the minimum and maximum, included. In your example the medium slider position (value=20) would correspond to 20 meters.

Comment: Hi @Costique.  Thanks for your replies.  I think I need to rephrase my question, because it's starting to seem like less of a slider issue and more of an issue related to how I need to resize the object's image at any given slider position to reflect its new position relative to the host image.